Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=1024M'
[Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=1024M'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Press any key to continue . . .](https://i.sstatic.net/YjPgaGTx.png)|  (Second Photo : 1)
Can someone help me please,i just tried to open server in minecraft,and then i saw this
